# PHP- if else statement not working?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$nav_next_id = $page_id + 1;

$sql = "SELECT page FROM plm WHERE id = '$nav_next_id'"; {
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($next_page = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($page_id + 1 > 24) 
    {
    $goto_next_page = 'some_page.php';
    } 
    else
    {
    $goto_next_page = $next_page['page_title'];     
    }
}
}
```

Basically a very straight forward next page button on simple site. Using the ID in the MYSQL table I can determine the next page from the current page.

All works well until I come to the last page. Which is page 24.

So i put an `if` in the loop saying if the page is > 24 go to some_page.php.

I am echoing `$goto_next_page` in my html.

However nothing is echoed from page 24, all other pages work fine. What wrong with this script?

---------UPDATE---------------- THIS IS HOW I GOT IT TO WORK ------------------

```
if($cur_page_id == 24) 
{
$goto_next_page = 'some_page.php';  
} 
else
{
$sql = "SELECT page FROM plm WHERE id = '$nav_next_id'"; {
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($next_page = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $goto_next_page = $next_page['page_title'];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use the [pre-increment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
if(++$page_id > 24)
```

Effectively, this means:

```
$page_id = $page_id + 1;

if($page_id > 24) {
```

This operator as well as its brother operator (the post-increment operator) both add 1 to the variable. However, the pre-increment operator adds one and then returns the new value. The post-increment operator, on the other hand, returns the value of the variable and then increments it by 1.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that `$page_id + 1 > 24` doesn't increment `$page_id` so it always remains the same. This makes sense because if you did:

```
$a = $page_id + 1;
```

You wouldn't expect `$page_id` to be incremented. You would expect `$a` to be 1 more than `$page_id`, but you'd expect `$page_id` to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple: the value of $page_id is not changing inside your loop.

Comment: Since the last page is page 24 I tried `if($page_id == 24)` That doesn't work either.

Comment: The point was that $page_id is set before the while loop, so that it looks like $page_id is never changing, and will always be checked against the same value . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$nav_next_id = $page_id + 1;

$sql = "SELECT page FROM plm WHERE id = '$nav_next_id'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($next_page = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($page_id + 1 > 24) 
    {
    $goto_next_page = 'some_page.php';
    } 
    else
    {
    $goto_next_page = $next_page['page_title'];     
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude you are not using the ID of the page in the loop that is why you are always getting the same result making it look like the if else is not working:

```
<?php 
     $nav_next_id = $page_id + 1; 
     $sql = "SELECT page FROM plm WHERE id = '$nav_next_id'"; 
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     while ($pages = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         if ($pages['id'] > 24) {
             $goto_next_page = 'some_page.php';
         }  
         else {
             $goto_next_page = $pages['page_title'];     
         }
     }
?>
```